# Part of quotation used for book title

Tags: quotes

I am using part of a quote for a book title. Do I need to put quotation marks around the book title and if so, do I need to include anything else to show that only part of the quotation is being used in the book title.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could include one or more examples of where you think speech/quotation marks are placed.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need to add punctuation. There are numerous book titles that utilize parts of quotations without either quotation marks or ellipses.  Consider the following:

> *The Sound and the Fury*
>
> *For Whom the Bell Tolls*
>
> *The Rains Came*

[Here](http://www.goodreads.com/list/show/8866.Book_Titles_Based_on_Lines_from_the_Bible) is a list of dozens of books whose titles are based on biblical quotes. There are undoubtedly many, perhaps hundreds, more.

This [site](http://www.nosweatshakespeare.com/resources/shakespeare-inspired-novel-titles/) suggests that there are thousands of literary titles based on Shakespearean quotes.

In virtually all of these examples, quotation marks and ellipses are not used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to one editor/publisher who felt it necessary to use both quotation marks and an ellipsis in a book title:
[Surely You're joking Mr. Feynman....](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Surely_You_re_Joking_Mr_Feynman.html?id=ZRoF9aN8qjAC&redir_esc=y)

The title quote was stated during Feynman's introduction tea at Princeton after his absent-minded response of "Both please." to the question "Cream or Lemon in your tea Mr. Feynman?"